# How to initialize a graphics g when building a RenderingEngine

Tags: java, swing, rendering-engine

So a buddy of mine built a `RenderingEngine` where it pretty much contains the methods that graphics has. That way you only need to call the `RenderingEngines` class's methods to render stuff to the screen. Without looking and trying to learn instead of cheating, im trying to replicate it based off my knowledge. I ran into a problem though. All my methods work its just that when the RenderingEngine class get initialized in my game class the graphics g in my RenderingEngine class is null after trying to get the JPanel's graphics. I don't know if i'm not understanding how this works and would love an explanation, ill put the code down below.

RENDERING CLASS BELOW:

```
package game.Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class RenderingEngine extends JPanel
{
    private Graphics g;
    public RenderingEngine()
    {
        g = this.getGraphics();
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
    }

    public void fillRect(Rectangle rect)
    {
        g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }

    public void drawRect(Rectangle rect)
    {
        g.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }

    public void setStringFont(Font font)
    {
        g.setFont(font);
    }

    public void drawString(String string, int x, int y)
    {
        g.drawString(string, x, y);
    }

    public void drawImage(BufferedImage image, Rectangle rect)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, this);
    }

    public void clear(Rectangle rect)
    {
        g.clearRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }

    public int widthofString(String string, Font font)
    {
        String text = string;
        AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform,true,true);
        Font f1 = font;
        int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getWidth());
        return textwidth;
        //int textheight = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getHeight());
    }

    public int heightofString(String string, Font font)
    {
        String text = string;
        AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform,true,true);
        Font f1 = font;
        //int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getWidth());
        int textheight = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getHeight());
        return textheight;
    }

    public void paint()
    {

    }
}
```

WHERE I INITIALIZE RENDERINGENGINE IN THE GAME CLASS:

```
private void Load()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    render = new RenderingEngine();
    frame.add(render);
    LoadContent();
    gameloop = new GameLoop();
    gameloop.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might consider it as unsatisfactory when I answer the question about "How to initialize a Graphics g" for a `JPanel` with ...

### Not at all!

You might want to have a look at the [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) article, or the article about [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) (which unfortunately was slightly messed up during the transition from Sun to Oracle, but still contains valuable and more detailed information than the other article).

The `Graphics` of a `JPanel` is, so to say, managed by the operating system, and represents an area on the screen where the painting may happen. When the panel is not yet visible, the `Graphics` that is returned by a call to `getGraphics()` may be `null`. It may also be `null` at other occasions. Particularly, when it is accessed from a thread that is not the event dispatch thread.

In general, as a rule of thumb:

**Never call `getGraphics` on a Component!**

One *possible* solution for such a "RenderingEngine" class would be to use the `Graphics` object of a `BufferedImage`. This should not be too complicated, but you'll have to consider several aspects here:

- When will the image be initialized?
- When will the graphics be initialized?
- When will the graphics be disposed?
- What happens when the panel is resized?
- ...

However, with this method, it should at least be *possible* to create such a "RenderingEngine" that is suitable for the intended usage.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try using the bufferedimage but for the visibility issue shouldn't it be visible since its added by the jframe which frame is set to be visible?

Comment: Again, you may **never** be sure whether `getGraphics` returns a valid `Graphics` Object. And BTW: At least in the posted code, the Frame is not made visible, and in any case, the *constructor* of the `RenderingEngine` class has to be called *before* it is added to a frame - and in the *constructor* you are trying to obtain the `Graphics` object. So this basically *can* not work...

Comment: Okay thanks right now tried to doing the bufferedimage way and i have no nulls but still not showing on the screen. I will look into before ask another question but thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Kunarklive You'll have to paint the image by overriding the `paintComponent` method of the panel. The image has to be painted into the `Graphics` that you receive in the `paintComponent` method, with `g.drawImage(image,0,0,null)`.

Comment: *"You'll have to paint the image.."*  Or simply display it in a label.

Comment: Alright got it done and it works ill post the classes shortly for anyone that needs references